# Why does this simple ScriptProcessorNode have so much latency?

Tags: javascript, javascript-audio-api

I'm having an issue with ScriptProcessorNode and lag.  Even when doing an incredibly simple process that just takes the sample and does `x %= 0.35`.  Why does this simple ScriptProcessorNode (included below) have so much latency?

The MDN says nothing about latency: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode

Also, I know that ScriptProcessorNode is to be deprecated soon, but audioWorklets aren't yet implemented, so this is the best there is.

```js
var baseFreq = 220;

var audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var osc = audioCtx.createOscillator();
osc.type = 'sine';
osc.frequency.value = baseFreq;
osc.start();

var intervals = [1, 1.125, 1.25, 1.5, 1.6666666, 1.875, 2, 4]

var index = 0;
function newTone() {
  index++;
  index %= intervals.length;
  osc.frequency.value = intervals[index] * baseFreq;
}

var modulus = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor();
modulus.onaudioprocess = function(audioProcessingEvent) {
  var inputBuffer = audioProcessingEvent.inputBuffer;
  var outputBuffer = audioProcessingEvent.outputBuffer;

  for (var channel = 0; channel < outputBuffer.numberOfChannels; channel++) {
    var inputData = inputBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
    var outputData = outputBuffer.getChannelData(channel);

    for (var sample = 0; sample < inputBuffer.length; sample++) {
      outputData[sample] = inputData[sample] % moduAmount;
    }
  }
}

var moduLow = 0.35;
var moduHigh = 2;
var moduAmount = moduLow;

function turnModulusOnOff() {
  if (moduAmount == moduLow)
    moduAmount = moduHigh;
  else
    moduAmount = moduLow;

}
 
var gain = audioCtx.createGain();
gain.gain.value = 0.05;

gain.connect(audioCtx.destination);
modulus.connect(gain)
osc.connect(modulus);
osc.connect(gain);

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", newTone);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="newTone()">Next Tone</button>
<button onclick="turnModulusOnOff()">Mute/Unmute Modulus</button>

<br>
To test, click anywhere and then press any key to change the tone.  Notice when Modulus is muted how responsive the tone change is.  Notice the lag between the sine frequency change and the modulus effect.
<br>
<b>For Extra Fun: Go crazy on your keyboard</b>
```

Comment: Wondered if that was what you meant. Well, if you refer to the docs for [createScriptProcessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createScriptProcessor) you can see that its constructor takes 3 parameters. These are bufferSize, numInputChans and numOutputChans. The number of channels defaults to 2 (for each) if not specified, while the _`bufferSize` defaults to a value deemed appropriate for the executing system_ - You've probably got a huge buffer which takes time to exhaust before the changes you make are observed. ;)

Comment: Also, the link you provided actually does talk about latency. About the bufferSize, it says: "Small numbers lower the latency, but large number may be necessary to avoid audio breakup and glitches."

Comment: I originally had the buffer size set to 256 for the example, but decided I would be better off not having that set for this question.  Changing it made no noticeable difference.

And the amount of latency is quite noteworthy.  This processor is doing almost nothing, but the ones which do anything of interest are extremely latent.

Comment: what's the hardware/browser you're running it on? (Both cpu and sound-hardware) I was reading the other day that as expected, onboard sound-cards suck, also that ASIO certified boards can handle buffer-sizes of just 256 samples at 44,100Hz with ease. I don't know enough to be willing to dismiss the hardware as the source of the consternation at this point.

Comment: I think the hardware is fine.  I can run DAW's, and nothing but this node has given me issues.  My guess is that the script runs single thread, so it's not being run until sometime after a bunch of other main thread stuff.